# Can I use multiple OpenVPN connections to speed-up transfer?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have OpenVPN server on my home LAN. It is connected to Internet via two internet providers with NAT and fixed global IPs.

So, I configured my server to listen connections from outside of both providers. And I can successfully connect to my LAN from outside.

But the problem is both providers provide asymmetric bandwidth. In other words it is relatively slow, if I copy something from my LAN to client.

Is it possible to have benefits from simultaneous connections? I can somehow configure IPs to be from the same subnet and etc.

Is it possible to be done and what is required?